# Soft body object not falling

Tags: physics

I have been working on a project for uni for a while now, I made a scene with a couple objects and some textures. It's going to be a ball falling from stairs, bouncing on collision. I made the ball a soft body object and added collision to the other objects. When playing the animation though, the ball stays in the air. It doesn't move at all. I made a new project and there the ball fell. Is there any way I accidentally disabled physics in original project and is it fixable? Or do I really just have to make the whole thing from scratch again...?

Comment: You may have disabled Gravity, either in the world, or in 'Field Weights' in the simulation?

Comment: Also, have you disabled the Goal option in the Physics panel?